# Motor speed control with Integral only loop

Tags: pid-controller

If you have a motor with a constant load and and travelling at a set speed, could you control the speed using only itegral action, as in theory the output would  stabalise when the error is equal to zero.

Obviously, it might take some to to reach the correct speed, but it should reach it nonetheless.

It seems that Proportional and Derivative are only useful when you need more immediate feedback (such as when the setpoint changes frequently, a non constant load, etc)

Comment: Since the response will be delayed pretty much, you will never get a stable speed, it will oscillate around the set-point. If you would like t reduce the oscillations, you will have to increase the response time (reduce the I-gain).

Comment: @Eugene, if the output I carried over, why would it oscillate, unless the load changed, etc. Wouldn't the system now know what the required motor output is to maintain the speed. I'm referring to an ideal system.

Comment: In ideal system, if the error is initially zero, then the integral term won't accumulate, so the system will run at this specific speed. But if it is not, the system will overshoot, because the accumulated error will have non-zero time to go back to zero, and then will overshoot again and again.

Comment: But I get what you're saying about reducing the integral gain. If you reduce it enough, it should be possible to stabalise the output without oscillations.

Comment: Probably possible in an over-damped system.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. A PI controller is used for motor speed loop. You have might encontered some other issue? You can tune the PI to be more stable as I only. So, that's why I don't see any reason to use integral control.

Comment: As Eugene says, with a suitably small integral gain, I don't see why you couldn't ultimately maintain the motor's speed, without significant oscillations.

Comment: A motor with load friction, inertia rapresents a certain known mathematical model.  A suitable controller is the one which added in the loop somehow acts quasi as an inverse of the motor model, therefore the resulting transfer function of closed system is 1 (pv=sp). Obviously this is not possible, but the closest candidate from those general controllers is a PI controller. Eliminating the P, you get an inadecuate controller, that's all.

Comment: Right, but I'm referring to an ideal system, where none of that would be considered. All you need to know is that a certain output is always equal to a certain speed.

Comment: Then you don't need a controller either.

Comment: What's "ideal"? Without friction and inertia you will get a nice sine in the output. As I said, to get a somewhat stable output with such a controller the open-loop system has to be overdamped.

Comment: What “Integral Action”?

Comment: A [very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/397731/7036) has been asked just yesterday, coincidentally.

Comment: By over damped, I assume you mean reduce integral gain?

Comment: Speed is the integral of acceleration. Add a second integrator and you may build an oscillator.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to maintain motor speed _in these specific conditions_ using only integral control. In fact, I-term is what introduces this exact behavior into full PID controller. However, as it was pointed out before, the response time of the system should be faster than integration time of a loop to avoid oscillation. The same effect can be achieved by severely reducing integral gain.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the above schematic is a fan speed control I built for my 300 watt linear power supply. Thermistors mounted to the heatsinks for the 2N3055 transistors provided the feedback voltage to the op-amp.

Three major things.

1) I had to heavily dampen the op-amp feedback with 100uF capacitors or they would do a rapid pulsing which you could hear in the fan motor.

2) I had to put a 10,000uF capacitor across the fan motor itself, to turn 10 second pulses into a continuous running current.

3) I had to add a 2.075 offset to the op-amps so they were 'OFF' if the heatsinks were cool or cold. This placed a safe -6.2 volts on the MOSFET's, shutting them off until the voltage due to heat (at pin 3 of op-amp) rose above 2.075 volts, creating a steep non-linear gain. The gain trim pot for the op-amp had a very narrow window in which things worked as they should.

The thermistors and the 2.075 volt ref came from a stable 5 volt regulator, so it never changed its behavior. Turn on the power supply and bypass resistors kept the fans at a very low RPM. A 10 second turn-on pulse made all fans run fast for ten seconds just to loosen them up. A heavy load at high voltage and current would soon have the fans running full speed, screaming loud. Take away the load and over 10 to 15 minutes they slowed down to idle speed.

The key to making this work good was **very heavy dampening of the op-amp and fan supply**, and an **offset voltage to create a 'comparator'** effect such that the motors would stay at idle speed until the heatsinks became warm, then hot.

This could be modified such that voltage or current or RPM feedback drove the fan speed, but with **bulky BLDC motors the integral is a long time constant**, else the op-amp will pulse-feed the motors or oscillate, making the motors buzz.

The *integral loop had to be slower than the mechanical response of the fan* motors or the op-amp became unstable as it raced ahead of the motors reaction time, thus pulsing or oscillating.

Comment: That last line in italic is actually THE most important part of the answer. Everything else could be irrelevant, depending on OP's implementation.

Comment: I've found systems which behaved nicely with I control, but didn't respond well to PI control.  I'm hoping someday I'll get a chance to revisit that system and figure out the theory behind why.  Something having to do with nested control loops and delays is my guess...

Answer (score -3):

## Simple answer

Speed is is proportional to Voltage with no load.
Reduced speed to  a “known” load depends on % of rated load  at that speed similar to a capacitive load with some resistance depending on inertial mass and real steady-state load equivalent to some resistance. Thus speed reduction with a long time delay.

The only integration is the rotational or linear momentum. **p=mv**

### **This is an open loop control system.** DETERMINED ONLY BY LOAD AND BY VOLTAGE ONLY

No P, I or D feedback nor control system.   -1 TO THE OP

————

### other info

Consider that the flux and current in ALL  motors are AC. This is no matter  whether they are brush commutated DC, BLDC or AC induction, etc.

If you can sense the fundamental commutation frequency without all of the harmonics and noise, then you can sense the RPM.  This is called Vector Speed control in EM machines.

If not, AND you know the exact load and speed vs load profile, then you can estimate the speed for some  current but only after it accelerates and runs out torque due to BEMF to accelerate any more at this load.

It reaches that speed after accelerating for some time, but this is a very slow process. It’s like stepping on the gas peddle a known distance and waiting for the car to reach that speed you know with that peddle pressure.

So what you need is current sensing for acceleration demand against controlled acceleration, then voltage debated for loading effects which are at least 16 % of no load speed in theory ( I wont explain but that is a matched motor RPM to  load for ideal system including Vp to Vrms of 0. 707 for a pseudo sine current.) ok enuf.

Then you need a velocity feedback system to regulate velocity, like a speedometer or a motor Tach or the commutated current converted to a pulse per pole per revolution per second. (Not as simple as this but you get the idea.).

Cruise  control in cars does not use D in PID control systems but rather delayed integral I  with limits and some P with limits on acceleration.

The derivative D would only be used in some modern collision avoidance system.  The same problem in motor load control systems. The current limits can be defined to limit acceleration and the voltage limits defined to after speed is reached and thus regulated.

AN OPEN LOOP SYSTEM IS SLOW. AND OPEN TO LOAD VARIATIONS.

Comment: Anyone who does not have the professional courtesy or aptitude to comment should be ashamed if they downvote. But that's your poor effort not a reflection on my efforts. you only make yourself and this site look bad

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine people are downvoting because it doesn't really seem to be relevant to the question. OP isnt asking about open loop, or the actual internal details of a physical control system, hes asking a purely theoretical control theory question

Comment: THEY ARE MISUNDERSTANDING THE QUESTION. There is no control system. You cannot fix a speed wit a fixed load  by any such vague remarks about D and P. No sensors mentioned. No control input, no feedback, nada. The question is invalid because it makes false assumptions about how it works

Comment: Actually, OP is asking about _integral control_ system, which implies closed loop, IMHO

Comment: I think you may be the one misunderstanding the question.  OP is pretty clearly asking about a closed-loop system (the "pid-controller" tag is used, and PID controller is pretty clearly referenced in the question, given the mention of "Proportional and Derivative" used for "feedback").  A sensor is therefore assumed.  I didn't downvote, but it doesn't appear your answer really addresses the question.  Also, insulting your downvoters is not a great way to convince them to reveal themselves.

Comment: @Selvek  WIth no input or sensor, it is far from clear.  Integrate what. Typical newbie question. Which part did I misunderstand>?  I am an expert in servo design

Comment: @Maple we know he is asking about **integral control**. But the question is invalid without specific feedback like current voltage, Tach anything. He seems to not know how any servo PID works on motors so he has thrown out the question with insufficient detail. The OP needs to learn more and ask an intelligent question

Comment: @Maple here’s an example if you the final speed of a car with a certain gas pedal pressure and you apply this from start. How long will it take>. Is this fixed load a control system? Can you imagine any PD solution for feedback?

Comment: I thought it would have been clear that if I mentioned PID, and the speed of a motor, a sensor would be assumed (whether it's an encoder, tachometer, etc).

Comment: Nope. what you want to control and choice of many sources of feedback are all related.   Normally you accelerate with a controlled current to max velocity then reduce to fixed load at fixed speed, there is no overshoot if you have a tach feedback. it is just high gain P error. but if you add disturbances, then you need feedback compensation based on J motor load inertia etc, torque, response time and phase margin using PI and some D for faster response and lead/lag filter for more margin. So the question was too vague. THink about how to control the gas pedal and how brain uses PID? response

Comment: Normally current, and encoder feedback are use with controlled ramp g and max V with error tolerances and if x control then other sources of feedback and separate control inputs. When I did this in '77 I only used a tach and comparator and drivers for an effective servo drive on a probe going thru a loop and back at 3 speeds. to control PWM voltage and wanted slow acceleration.  Every servo is different and your question cannot be answered. **Insufficient specs**